# Adding two different company users - Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

We are using Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online) for our development and have added all the users from my company with a valid MSDN license. (username@company.com)

Now I have few developers from our client who also have a valid MSDN license from their company. When i'm trying to add my client developers in our TFS online, its not recognizing their names( maybe active directory ?).

Is there a way to add two different companies user in one team project?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Azure Active Directory (AAD) you need to add any users as a foreign principal to that directory.

You can add either an MSA or another AAD account to give them access. Works pretty good, and i have people from more than 6 different companies on mine.

Answer (score 1):

To add users to a team project in Team Services, your team must sign in with Microsoft accounts unless your Team Services account uses a directory to control access. If it does, users must be directory members to get access. If you have directory administrator access, you can add usrs to the directory. If not, work with the directory administrator to add users. Check: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/add-team-members-vs